# How to subtract a month from Date object?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, subtraction

How do I subtract a month from a date object in VB.NET?

I have tried:

```
Today.AddMonths(-1)
```

However, given that Today is 01-Jan-2010, the result I get is 01-Dec-2010. The answer I want is 01-Dec-2009.

Is there a convenient way of doing this within the .NET framework?

Comment: OK.  This question (and the answers) are really, really confusing me.  What is the exact code you are using that exhibits the above problem?  I typed Today.AddMonths(-1) into the debugger and it works properly, subtracting one from the year if you are in January.

Comment: Hi Jason. The problem wasn't actually that .AddMonths() wasn't working. The problem was that Date objects are immutable. I hadn't assigned the return value of .AddMonths() to a variable. For example, I was doing someDate.AddMonths(-1), when it should be someDate = someDate.AddMonths(-1).

Comment: In that case, though, someDate would not change.  i.e. in your example, it would still be set to 01-Jan-2010, not 01-Dec-2010.  Hence, my confusion.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You actually have to transport Today into a variable and let that assignment work there. The following code will produce the result you expect (I just verified it because your post made me think twice).

```
Dim dt As DateTime = Date.Today
dt = dt.AddMonths(-2)

Dim x As String = dt.ToString()
```

Answer (score 8):

This works fine, you need to remember that the DateTime is imutable.

```
Dim d As DateTime
d = New DateTime(2010, 1, 1)
d = d.AddMonths(-1)
```

Have a look at [DateTime Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(VS.71).aspx)

> A calculation on an instance of
>   DateTime, such as Add or Subtract,
>   does not modify the value of the
>   instance. Instead, the calculation
>   returns a new instance of DateTime
>   whose value is the result of the
>   calculation.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim d As DateTime = #1/1/2010#
d = d.AddMonths(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I  have used the following and it works.

```
Dim dtToday As DateTime = Date.Today
dtToday = dtToday.AddMonths(-2)
```